# ZSH local keyword "not an identifier"

Tags: zsh

When executing `test test.txt` (assuming `test.txt` exists) in zsh. I receive a `test:local: not an identifier:` error, when `test` is defined as:

```
function test() { local test=$(gzip -c "$1" | wc -c); echo "$test" }
```

Now, I've narrowed this down to the use of the `local` keyword, as no error is thrown when the `local` keyword is removed in:

```
function test() { test=$(gzip -c "$1" | wc -c); echo "$test" }
```

I am interested in why the error is thrown only when the variable is scoped, if this is an issue with how I'm scoping the variable in ZSH, I am interested in the correct way to scope the variable.

Comment: What version of Zsh are you using? Your function works fine on both 5.0.8 and 5.0.2 in my setups. Any luck with putting the `local test` on a separate line, like `local test; test=$(...)`?

Comment: I am using 5.0.8. Putting them on separate lines *does* work, but why?

Comment: When you do `local var=$()`, always quote your command substitution, i.e., `local var="$()"`, because multiple tokens in the result of command substitution cause problems. Not to say it fixes the issue at hand. Also, `function test()` is the worst coding style possible. Either do `function test` or `test()`. Do not use both.

Comment: @4ae1e1 Quoting the command substitution also does indeed fix the issue. Thanks for the heads up.